# how to render a 3d map with html5/js with point of interest

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, openstreetmap

i need to rendere a 3d map like https://www.airbnb.it/map and put on it some "point" at runtime, loading them dinamically via rest. have someone information about building a 3d map (eventually getting data from openstreetmap) via js or others techniques?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to use a WebGL library like Cesium (http://cesiumjs.org/).

Answer (score 2):

There are already various 3D maps based on OSM data. Take a look at [3D](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/3D) and [3D Development](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/3D_Development) in the OSM wiki.